# Disable image compression in Chrome mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, google-chrome

When using Chrome mobile on iOS and Android, we noticed that when "Reduce Data Usage" is turned on, the images on our modelling agency website get compressed by a significant amount. We would like to somehow disable this, since our portfolio has to consist of high quality photos.

Is there any HTML meta tag, CSS rule or any JS hack to force disable this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `<img src="example.png" pagespeed_no_transform>` where

The 'Optimize Images' filter won't optimize an image (though it might still cache extend it) if it has the pagespeed_no_transform attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works, but we have many photos, isn't there an easier way, like a CSS rule?

Comment: @TrisztánThar maybe with js you can tag all your img and then add that attribute

Comment: @TrisztánThar: not sure that it has the right rule, but you could write a small python script that will parse all your html, find each <img> and adds "pagespeed_no_transform" tag

Comment: @euvl I don't think is neseccary here.Just a bit of Jquery

Comment: @euvl I am facing similar issue but i have applied image using `background: url("@{imagePath}/homepage/bg.jpg") no-repeat center fixed` css property. Can i achieve this ``pagespeed_no_transform`` using css ?

Answer (score 0):

Use some jquery
For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img").attr (" pagespeed_no_transform",true );
});
```